# How to Play YUV sequence of images with JSP

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-streaming, javacv, yuv

I could get YUV images from Camera for 20 frames per second, i want to play it as live streaming on JSP page.

I have done some research about JMF/FFMpeg, maybe they could work with J2SE(Swing),but seems hard to work on web application(Tomcat+JSP pages).

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you hoping to create a web page that directly plays uncompressed YUV frames from the camera via the network? How large are the YUV frames? What YUV colorspace (e.g., 12- or 16-bit colorspace)? Over what kind of network-- e.g., gigabit LAN or public internet?

Comment: @MultimediaMike, another C program will capture YUV frames from remote camera at a rate of 20 frames per second, and my JSP application need to live streaming those frames on web page. All traffic is in LAN.

Comment: Are you planning to display the video using a Java applet within the JSP-generated HTML page? Or will the JSP page have some other mechanism to display? There are lots of ways to accomplish what you want; I'm trying to get a feel for how you plan to approach this.

Comment: @MultimediaMike, i prefer to display the live streaming with JSP or HTML5 etc.Applet will be the last option when other alternatives could not be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, here's a solution that you might find feasible:

- Client-side (browser): Code that accesses the server and streams 20 RGB frames each second and draws them on the page (like in a canvas element). The browser will be much happier drawing RGB images rather than YUV. For YUV, it would need to do conversion to RGB and that might be inefficient, especially in JavaScript.
- Server-side: Read the raw YUV frames and convert them to RGB frames. You can leverage FFmpeg to do this or just handle the colorspace conversion yourself (the formulas are easy to find).

Be advised of the bandwidth implications, however. For example, a 320x240 video frame has 76800 pixels. 20 frames per second works out to 1536000 pixels per second. Assuming 32-bit RGB, that's 6144000 bytes, or about 6 MB of raw video data per second, *per client*.

Comment: Currently my Java program will call the c DLL to get frames periodically,i'm not sure whether it is the correct way to do live streaming. The frame is 1024*768, and at most i need to support monitor 16 cameras at the same time. In all it needs bandwidth about 1G per second.

Comment: This is what image compression is for. You may want to run those raw YUV frames through a JPEG compressor and send those over to the clients. You should be able to write JavaScript to update display 20 JPEGs per second.

Comment: Yes,i could compress YUV frames before send it over the network. But one issue is that the time needed to convert YUV to RGB is huge. Do you have some good suggestions?Thanks~

Comment: Do you mean convert YUV to PNG? Is there any material for reference?

Comment: Actually, I just re-read the rest of the conversation: Try JPEG first. The browser should be able to do the heavy lifting and decode those efficiently, and they will implicitly be decoded into RGB images so you can slap them onto a canvas. PNG would also work but compression wouldn't be as good for this type of data and would be slower to both encode and decode (even though it would be native RGB).

Comment: So i just need to convert YUV to JPEG images, and let browser show the JPEG images?

Comment: Conceptually, but you still need to write the infrastructure to stream the JPEGs to the browser.

Comment: Yeah,this is the key point. Currently i periodically refresh the browser with JS interval, i think maybe this is not the correct way. Do you have some good suggestion to stream the JPEG to browser? Comet or WebSocket?

Comment: I'm thinking that there has to be a better, easier, pre-packaged solution. In lieu of that (or with the determination to homebrew), it should look something like: Server continually reads YUV frames and compresses to JPEG files, probably storing as timestamped temporary files. HTML/JSP page uses XMLHttpRequest to ask for new JPEG packages and call browser APIs to decode the image and slap it onto the canvas (or perhaps as the canvas to show the new JPEG-- it can probably decode it directly).

Comment: Good luck. I don't expect this to be a great solution, especially with 16 cameras crowding the bandwidth on a single LAN. You may need to toy with JPEG compression levels and sacrifice some image quality.

Comment: Sure.I know live streaming on JSP with 16 cameras is not a good idea, just try to make it work~